# How do I show "Choose Your Option" insead of "Add to Cart" when products have variables?

Tags: shopify

On shopify Im trying to show "Choose your option" and have the button click to the product url if it has multiple options, and have products with no option show the standard "Add to cart".

I have this beginning template but I cant seem to make it work.

```
<form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="AddToCartForm" class="quick-add-to-cart small--hide clearfix">
{% if product.variants.size > 1 %}
  <select id="product-select-{{ product.id }}" name='id' class="text-center">
  {% for variant in product.variants %}
  {% if variant.available %}
    <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %} selected="selected" {% endif %} data-sku="{{ variant.sku }}" value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }}</option>
  {% else %}
    <option disabled="disabled">
    {{ variant.title }} - {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
    </option>
  {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  </select>
  {% else %}
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product.variants.first.id }}" />
  {% endif %}

  {% if product.available %}
    <button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart" class="btn btn-mini text-center" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Quick Add To Cart', '{{ product.type }}', '{{ product.title }}');">Add To Cart</button>
  {% else %}
    <h6>Out of Stock</h6>
  {% endif %}
</form>
```

Here is my edit but it did not work, and is giving me errors as well.

```
<form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="AddToCartForm" class="quick-add-to-cart small--hide clearfix">
{% if product.variants.size > 1 %}
    <button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart"  class="btn btn-mini text-center" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Quick Add To Cart', '{{ product.type }}', '{{ product.title }}');">Add To Bag</button>
  {% else %}
      <button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart"  class="btn btn-mini text-center" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Quick Add To Cart', '{{ product.type }}', '{{ product.title }}');">Add To Bag</button>
  {% endif %}

 {% if product.available %}
    <button type="submit" name="add" id="AddToCart" class="btn btn-mini text-center" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Quick Add To Cart', '{{ product.type }}', '{{ product.title }}');">Add To Cart</button>
  {% else %}
    <h6>Out of Stock</h6>
  {% endif %}
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show us what exactly have you tried, since the provided code is a "default" product form without any visible "try" to modify it in some way?

Comment: Sure, sorry I didnt post it because it didnt work, I also know just super basic coding so this version is just giving me errors. Updated my original post.